# Answer questions sequence using Open3.popen3 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, stdout, stdin, disk-partitioning

I'm trying to answer different questions from external script using Ruby.

This is working code

```
Open3.popen3("cp -i 1 0") {|i,o,e,p|
  i.write "y\n"
  i.close
  o.read.split("\n").each {|l| puts l }
}
```

But, what if external command asks a question and then asks another question, if first answer was true?

Example code

```
Open3.popen3("/sbin/parted /dev/sda rm 1") {|i,o,e,p|
  i.write "n\n"
  i.close
  o.read.split("\n").each { |l| puts l }
  exit_status = p.value
  puts "Exit status: " + (exit_status.success? ? 'succeeded' : 'failed')
}
```

Its always failed. Doesn't matter if answer `y\n` or `n\n`. When I hit `n` in the console, parted stops and partition stays as is. When I hit `y`, I receive another confirmation where I should answer with "Ignore/Cancel" (`i` or `c`). How to answer on external call correctly? First "yes", second "ignore" (`y` then `i`)?

Answer (score 0):

In that case, doesn't `i.write "y\ni\n"` work? Works for me..

Comment: It doesn't work. May be there is another way how to do the same?